# The raster or shapefile exported from Ecognition does not align with the original raster when I open it in QGIS

Tags: raster, alignment, ecognition

The raster or shapefile exported from Ecognition does not align with the original raster when I open it in QGIS.

I'm using Ecognition to classify a raster, but when I export the shapefile and open it in QGIS (or ENVI), they do not get aligned, a detachment of about 10meters occurs. They are in the same coordinate system: WGS84.

When I open the original raster in Ecognition and export, misalignment also occurs.

RASTER ORIGINAL:

Origin = (-54.583819789617955,-22.641199008303921)

Pixel Size = (0.000000496266000,-0.000000460594000)

RASTER EXPORT FROM ECOGNITION:

Origin = (-54.583819789617955,-22.641025856415922)

Pixel Size = (0.000000496266000,-0.000000496266000)

RASTER ORIGINAL:

Upper Left  ( -54.5838198, -22.6411990) ( 54d35' 1.75"W, 22d38'28.32"S)

Lower Left  ( -54.5838198, -22.6434347) ( 54d35' 1.75"W, 22d38'36.37"S)

Upper Right ( -54.5769937, -22.6411990) ( 54d34'37.18"W, 22d38'28.32"S)

Lower Right ( -54.5769937, -22.6434347) ( 54d34'37.18"W, 22d38'36.37"S)

Center      ( -54.5804067, -22.6423169) ( 54d34'49.46"W, 22d38'32.34"S)

RASTER EXPORT FROM ECOGNITION:

Upper Left  ( -54.5838198, -22.6410259) ( 54d35' 1.75"W, 22d38'27.69"S)

Lower Left  ( -54.5838198, -22.6434347) ( 54d35' 1.75"W, 22d38'36.37"S)

Upper Right ( -54.5769937, -22.6410259) ( 54d34'37.18"W, 22d38'27.69"S)

Lower Right ( -54.5769937, -22.6434347) ( 54d34'37.18"W, 22d38'36.37"S)
Center      ( -54.5804067, -22.6422303) ( 54d34'49.46"W, 22d38'32.03"S)

Here's an example image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data for eCognition has to be in a projected coordinate system (and not a geographic) such as UTM. Otherwise it will screw up your raster-file. That will do the trick.
This trick also worked for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure u ticked "Use geocoding [box]". I have that problem too...i found this answer in ecognition community.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The input data for eCognition has to be in a projected coordinate system (and not a geographic) such as UTM. Otherwise it will screw up your raster-file. That will do the trick. Please also see the eCognition Community for issues like that.

Cheers